# How To set Active Page in IWorkbenchPage

Tags: java, eclipse

I am running an application as **`Eclipse`** application where some operation is getting performed on a file and correspondingly other file is modified

**I am getting the file like this**:

```
    Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {  
        @Override
        public void run() {
            IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
            IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
            IWorkbenchPage activePage = workbenchWindow.getActivePage();
            IEditorPart editor = activePage.getActiveEditor();
            IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();
            IPath path = ((FileEditorInput)input).getPath();
}
}});
```

I am performing some operation on different file based on some input, and i want to set that as active page in running `eclipse` application.

I am not able to figure out how to set that active page.

I went through question but have not found exact question.

Comment: There is only one page in a workbench window. Editors are all on the same page.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the info,  I want to display the new file in view, I have a File object. I want that to be displayed in running eclipse application

Comment: So you want to open a new editor? Is the file in the workspace or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes a new file editor in running eclipse application, Yes the file is in workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one page in a workbench window. Editors are all on the same page.

For a file in the workspace you use `IFile` to reference the file.

There are lots of ways to get the `IFile`, for example if you have the path relative to the workspace root use:

```java
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
IFile file = root.getFile(new Path("path relative to workspace root"));
```

If you have an absolute path `File` you can use:

```java
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
URI location = file.toURI();
IFile[] files = root.findFilesForLocationURI(location);
```

Once you have the `IFile` you can open the default editor for the file using:

```java
IDE.openEditor(activePage, file);
```

or you can specify a specific editor id with:

```java
IDE.openEditor(activePage, file, "the editor id");
```

`IDE` is `org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE`

Comment: Yeah, It is working fine, Thanks ! @greg-449 there is dialogue box to load the file with new changes can we automatically handle that to accept

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question - ask a new Question with more details.

Comment: Question is , Whenever the file will be loaded in editor, There will be a popup dialogues saying load the content with recent changes, because the file was changed earlier, So is there any way to accept the dialogue box automatically

Comment: Not that I know off.

Comment: Hi @greg-449 1 question, I was able to set activePage and open the file but i want the cursor to be at certain line say 100th line or at line where some text is found, How to achieve that

Comment: Please ask a new question.